# Switch Laravel locale with Axios

Tags: laravel, session, localization, locale, axios

I want to change my locale with axios call:

```
changeLanguage(code) {
                return axios
                    .put(`/api/lang/` + code)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        return "Error switching language";
                        console.log(err.response);
                    });
            },
```

My API route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['sessions']], function () {
    Route::put('lang/{language}', 'LanguageController@switchLang');
});
```

My sessions middleware:

```
'sessions' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ]
```

My LanguageController:

```
public function switchLang(Request $request, $lang)
{
        session(['applocale' => $lang]);
        app()->setLocale($lang);
}
```

My IndexController:

```
public function index()
{
        \Debugbar::info("Index getLocale is: " . app()->getLocale());
        \Debugbar::info("Index Session locale is: " . session('applocale'));
}
```

The problem is that LanguageController can't set session variable that can be read from IndexController. It seams that they don't share same session variables. And every time I refresh the page it shows old language.

What is the right way to change current locale with Axios?

Comment: What's the route definition for this index method?  API routes are normally stateless.

Comment: @Devon route definition is in web.php: Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');